# Determine Next Day 6PM

Tags: php, datetime, date

```
<?php
$start_date = "12/10/2009 11:30";
echo "<br>start_date: $start_date<br>";

$due_date1   = date("m/d/Y H:i", strtotime("+1 day".$start_date));
$due_date2   = date("m/d/Y H:i", strtotime("+2 day 6pm".$start_date));
echo "<br>due_date1: $due_date1<br>";
echo "<br>due_date2: $due_date2<br>";
?>
```

See my code , I'm trying to get two dates from a start_date.

First one due_date1 is the exact 24 hours form the start_date and the second one due_date2 is 6pm after the second day of start_date

due_date1 is working correctly

What is wrong with due_date2 calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might as well go for

```
$due_date2   = date("m/d/Y 18:00", strtotime("+2 day".$start_date));
```